# Flutter: read file from path which is outside application directory

Tags: flutter

My app is registered as `.pdf` file opener, when I use `"open with"` function on my android device, in flutter application I receive path to file via [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) package. The problem is that the path I'm receiving is `content://external_files/Download/some_file.pdf` which I can't read since it's not a valid path and android will throw me `java.io.FileNotFoundException`, how can I get a proper path to my file? both for iOS and Android.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/uri_to_file maybe?

Comment: That might work, but as I see it's only for android.

Comment: the docs say: "A Flutter plugin for converting supported uri to file. Supports Android & iOS"

Comment: You're right, I wasn't payint too much attention and I only read about that content:// is only for android.